# Normal Subgroups in $\mathbb{Z_9}$

Tags: group-theory

> Decide whether $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I am given $G = (\mathbb{Z_9},+), H = <3>$.

My book defines a subgroup like this:

"A subgroup  $H$ of $G$ is said to be a *normal subgroup* if for every $b \in G$ and every $h \in H$ , $b^{-1}hb\in H$". It just gives this definition of what a subgroup is, without any concrete examples to follow up and thus am sure how to incorporate that into solving my problem. I looked at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79734/whats-an-easy-way-of-proving-a-subgroup-is-normal), but still seem to get no where.

**A follow up question:**

So is there a general method of determining whether a subgroup is indeed normal to a group?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to search for the following facts:

> (i) If $G$ is abelian, then every subgroup of $G$ is normal.
>
> (ii) Let $S$ be a subset of $G$, then $\langle S\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$, namely the subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$.

Answer (score 0):

As addition means it is Abelian, it implies that all of its subgroup is normal, because of the definition

If N is a subgroup of G, $\forall$ n $\epsilon$ N and $\forall$ g $\epsilon$ G, 
$gng^-1$ = $n_1$, $\exists n_1 \epsilon$ N

As + is Abelian, $gng^-1 = ngg^-1$ = n, so it must be normal.

To solve  G=(Z9,+),H=<3>G=(Z9,+),H=<3>. You can make a Cayley Table to prove H is subgroup of G first. Then, by addition is abelian, H is normal to G.

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow your definition of a normal subgroup.

You have a subgroup $H = <3>$ of $G = (\mathbb{Z}_9,+)$. This is a normal subgroup if for every $b \in G$ and $h \in H$, $b^{-1}hb \in H$.

Take an element b in G, and find out what $b^{-1}hb$ is for some $h \in H$. Lets try $b = 8 \in \mathbb{Z}_9$. $b^{-1}hb = -8 + h + 8$ where $h \in H$.

As addition is commutative in $\mathbb{Z}_9$, $b^{-1}hb = -8 + h + 8 = h -8 + 8 = h \in H$.

So in that example, we did after all end up with something that was still in $H$. The question you have to answer is whether that happens with every $h \in H$ and $b \in G$. You don't actually have to check them all, you can prove it using the properties of your group.

Your group is in fact what is called an *abelian group*, making this problem easier than it otherwise could be. That means your group operation (here it is $+$) is commutative.