# Finding an homomorphism by given normal subgroup.

Tags: matrices, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

I was asked in an exam

> Let $n \in \mathbb N$. Let  $S = SL (2, \mathbb Z)$. Let $$ \left\{ A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in S,\quad \begin{matrix} a \equiv 1 \pmod{n}, & b \equiv 0 \pmod{n}\\c \equiv 0 \pmod{n},& d \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \end{matrix}\right\}$$  Determine whether $A$ is a normal subgroup of $S$.

I have proved this by checking subgroup criterion and then showed that $\forall s \in S , \forall a \in a: \quad s^{-1}as\in A.$ Then I completed the proof.

My question is:

> how should I define the homomorphism $\varphi$, so kernel of $\varphi$ will be $A$?

First thought that is from $S = SL (2, \mathbb Z)$ to $S = SL (2, \mathbb Z_n^*)$ would be fine but then I confused if $\varphi$ is really a homomorpism. I tried to check if $\varphi$ is homomorphism by checking where entries of $s_1,s_2 \in S$ goes and where entries of $s_1s_2$ goes. I think that for $s_1 = \begin{pmatrix} x_{1,1}&x_{1,2}\\x_{2,1}&x_{2,2} \end{pmatrix}$, each entry $x_{i,j}$  goes to $x_{i,j}\pmod n$ but this doesn't have to be in $SL (2, \mathbb Z_n^*)$, because $n$ doesn't have to be prime. This is where I stucked.

I have looked that if similar question was asked here and I saw some questions similar but not the same and after seeing that questions I still can't find proper answer.

Any suggestion would be fine. Thanks!

Comment: You just need the canonical projection onto the quotient.

Comment: There is two times $a\equiv 1\bmod n$ in what you wrote, and none for $c$. It looks like a typo somewhere.

Comment: Anytime you have a normal subgroup of a group,  there's a projection onto the quotient group,  given by $\pi(g)=gN$ for any $g\in G$.  It's a homomorphism from $G$ onto $G/N$ with kernel $N.$

Comment: Can we interpret this  as $G/N$ is always isomorphic to $G/N$

Comment: That's of course true. The first isomorphism theorem says that here, if you like.

Comment: If you already know that $N\lt G$ is normal, then one can always construct the projection $\phi\colon G\to G/N$ where $\phi(g)=gN$. This has kernel $N$. What is not always trivial or obvious is the following: suppose we have a group $G$ and a subgroup $N$, *which we do not already know to be normal*. Can we find some group $K$ and some homomorphism $\phi\colon G\to K$ with $\ker(\phi)=N$? This is a problem of our *ability* to discover such a map, not of whether the map exists (it exists if and only if $N$ is normal). Are you asking if there is some map that is "clearer" than the direct proof?

Comment: When writing this question my aim was to prove $A$ is normal in $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ because we can construct homomorphism $\varphi$ with kernel $A$. Because from direct proof I know that $A$ is normal in $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ so I can find homomorphism. But I couldn't find one and yes that's the question I was trying to ask.

Comment: It is often difficult to find such examples, because you need the quotient group to be "know" in some independent way, and you may not know the quotient as anything other than a quotient.

Comment: What you wrote is not even a subgroup. You are attempting to define a the level $n$ principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(n)$, but you've made a typo: It should be $c\equiv 0$ (mod $n$).  Then $\Gamma(n)$ is the kernel of the reduction mod $n$ homomorphism to $SL(2, {\mathbb Z}_n)$.

Comment: This seems to be a case as in your comment, @ArturoMagidin: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3838188/1092170

Comment: @Devo I don't see any comment of mine in that link. But I've said it before, yes. E.g. my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/79739/742).

Comment: I expressed myself badly, @ArturoMagidin: the link is an example of your comment here above.